# Terminology for transforming a directed acyclic graph into a tree

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology, directed-graphs

I am looking for the term of converting a directed acyclic graph (DAG) into a tree by traversing its topologically ordered nodes and copying the subtrees of the nodes with in-degree $> 1$.

Such a transformation appears in many questions in this site, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397641/converting-directed-acyclic-graph-dag-to-tree) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624778/how-to-convert-directed-acyclic-graph-dag-to-tree?rq=1), and across the web (e.g [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Any-DAG-can-be-converted-into-a-tree-by-using-T-DAG-tree_fig4_220386988)).

The term **arboreal decomposition** appears [here](http://web.cs.elte.hu/~kiraly/alkszem/Obdrzalek.DAG-width.pdf) (p. 818, Algorithm 1) and [here](https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/seminar/20060504110012001-149865.pdf) (p. 145/177) seems strongly connected to what I am looking for, but not exactly the same. However, I could not find the exact term of this graph operation.

More specifically, I am currently writing a paper and I need
1. A reference that this transformation is well-defined
2. What's the name of this transformation?
3. Is there some graph theory terminology could be used to depict this operation on a DAG with exactly one node with in-degree $> 1$, better than depicting the graph explicitly? (to make my paper more elegant)

Comment: How does this compare with the McCammond expansion (see Section 2 in [Jon McCammond, John Rhodes, Benjamin Steinberg, *Geometric Semigroup Theory*, arXiv:1104.2301v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2301v1) and §2.5 in [John Rhodes, Anne Schilling, *Unified theory for finite Markov chains*, arXiv:1711.10689v3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10689v3))?

Comment: I'm accustomed to calling this process "unraveling" the dag. Unfortunately, I don't remember where I learned this terminology and I'm unsure how common it is.

Comment: See p. 8 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.02309.pdf. The paper is in the context of network theory, and discusses a procedure called TENN for expanding networks to rooted trees.

Comment: Did you every find an answer to this question?

Comment: This is a directed version of the "universal covering graph": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_graph#Universal_cover. Nodes in the expanded tree correspond to paths in the graph starting with a root node. Unfortunately, I can't find a reference for a *directed* version of this concept; people seem to care more about the *undirected* version, which typically gives you an infinite graph. But imposing direction seems like an obvious generalization to me.